# How do I know if my Asp.Net web application was victim of a sync -> async deadlock?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I suspect my Asp.Net Framework web application was victim of a deadlock caused by sync code calling async code. My question is; how do I for a fact know that this is what happened? Is there any way to make a diagnosis of this?

And can someone explain how I could possibly recreate this in an Asp.Net Framework (IIS hosted) scenario? I would like to be able to test the changes I make to prove that I solved the problem.

The reason I suspect this is that during a moment of higher load the web application became totally unresponsive for about 10 minutes, and the last thing I could see prior to this in the logs was a TaskCanceledException from a HttpClient async call, called from sync code in a fashion that I do think is considered to be at risk for deadlocks.

Unfortunately I cannot change the fact that the code in my application will start off in a sync manner because of legacy dependencies.

My candidate for solution for this specific scenario is to make sync calls all the way, meaning not using HttpClient but instead rolling my own client using HttpRequest. But I would like to be able to prove that I made a difference with this change.

Comment: Sounds to me like you HttpClient connection timed out, possibly due to a transient network problem. That is just a guess. Could be a bunch of other things, too. I wouldn't assume the problem is a deadlock without more evidence.

Comment: @JohnWu yeah, but that's my question; what evidence? What are the clues to know that? But good point, maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing here, now that I think of it, parts of the application was still up and running, but parts that used the same HttpClient code was totally dead.